# printing multiple lists vertically?

Tags: python, list, printing

Good afternoon,
I am trying to print 8 lists veritcally and can't seem to find the right formatting. I know you can print a list vertically by...

```
for x in list:
    print(x)
```

However, I do not know how i would print multiple lists vertically in a row.
I was thinking something along the lines of this....

```
 for L in range(0,7):
    print("    ", end="")
    try:
        for column in tableaus:
            print("{***}".format(str(tableaus[0][8])))

    except IndexError:
        raise RuntimeError("error occurred creating the tableaus")
```

Tableaus, if printed by itself looks like this:

```
[[K♠, 5♠, 10♥, 2♥, 7♦, Q♣, 4♣], [Q♠, 4♠, 9♥, A♥, 6♦, J♣, 3♣], [J♠, 3♠, 8♥, K♦, 5♦, 10♣, 2♣], [10♠, 2♠, 7♥, Q♦, 4♦, 9♣, A♣], [9♠, A♠, 6♥, J♦, 3♦, 8♣], [8♠, K♥, 5♥, 10♦, 2♦, 7♣], [7♠, Q♥, 4♥, 9♦, A♦, 6♣], [6♠, J♥, 3♥, 8♦, K♣, 5♣]]
```

I want it to look more like this:

```
l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l   
i  i  i  i  i  i  i  i 
s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  
t  t  t  t  t  t  t  t  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  5  6  7  8 
1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Here's a hint: use `zip` to get each row that needs printing in a tuple.

Comment: the entire for loop could be done as: `for L in tableaus:
    try:
        print([column for column in L]))`...etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to rotate the lists

```
for l in zip(*tableaus):
    print(*l)
```

Without `zip`, you could do something like

```
for i in len(tableaus[0]):
     print(' '.join([l[i] for l in tableaus]))
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! unfortunately this program i am working on is for a school project, and I am not allowed to use zip. Is there any other way to do this, just by playing with .format()?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code solves your problem. It also works if lists are of a different length.

```
tableaus = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]
tableas_empty = [False for tableau in tableaus]

separator = ' '
empty_value = ' '

while not all(tableas_empty):
    row = []
    for i, item in enumerate(tableaus):
        if item:
            value = item.pop(0)
            row.append(str(value))
        else:
            tableas_empty[i] = True
            row.append(empty_value)
    separator.join(row)
```

Result:

```
'a 1'
'b 2'
'c 3'
'  4'
'  5'
```